# Split array where previous value is greater than present value

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to split this array:

```
arr = [3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3]
```

where the previous element is greater than the present element. The result should be another array:

```
[[3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: Show us your attempts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
arr.slice_when(&:>).to_a
# => [[3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: ...or `arr.chunk_while(&:<=).to_a`, which is not surprising as [Enumerable#chunk_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) and [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) are [yin and yang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang)..

Answer (score 0):

```
def spliter array
  splited_array = []
  temp = []
  last = array[0]
  array.each do |element|
    if element >= last
      temp << element
    else
      splited_array << temp
      temp = [element]
    end
    last = element
  end
  splited_array << temp
end
```

Answer (score 0):

recursive example.

```
arr = [3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3]

def ans(list, temps, target)
  temps = [target[0]] if temps == []
  if !target[1]
    list << temps
  elsif target[0] < target[1]
    ans(list, temps << target[1], target[1...target.size])
  else
    ans(list << temps, [target[1]], target[1...target.size])
  end
end

ans([], [], arr)
```